# How to access an IP address as if on a different network using SSH

Tags: ssh, ip, routing, router, port-forwarding

In preparation for a lengthy business trip, I set up my router such that I can access my home computer over the internet via port forwarding over SSH. One thing I neglected to do was setup access to my router remotely. Normally, I can just access the router configuration page via `192.168.1.1`.

I know that it's possible to tunnel traffic through SSH, but **how do I access an IP address as if I were on my home network using SSH?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already away from home and didn't enable the port mapping to the SSH port, you may not have any recourse.

If you *do* have SSH access to your system, you can establish an SSH tunnel through your exposed host to access some local resources.

For example, if your router's configuration page is: 192.168.1.1 and you're connecting from a Unix-like host (you didn't specify the operating systems involved):

`sudo ssh -L 80:192.168.1.1:80 username@external_IP`

Where `external_IP` is the internet-facing IP address of your home computer/router and `username` is the user name on that system. If the connection is successful, you'll be able to point your mobile system to `http://127.0.0.1` to access the router page.

Answer (score 2):

Just use ssh port forwards. If 1.2.3.4 is the p of your router, then:

```
$ ssh user@1.2.3.4 -L8888:192.168.1.1:80
```

After connecting, enter `http://localhost:8888` in your browser, and you should see your router's login page.